# How to verify if text is selected

Tags: android-espresso

I need to verify if a TextView is selected. Here is the object:

```
TextView{
    id=2131230879,
    res-name=title,
    visibility=VISIBLE,
    width=101,
    height=144,
    has-focus=false,
    has-focusable=false,
    has-window-focus=true,
    is-clickable=false,
    is-enabled=true,
    is-focused=false,
    is-focusable=false,
    is-layout-requested=false,
    is-selected=true,
    root-is-layout-requested=false, 
    has-input-connection=false, 
    x=71.0, 
    y=0.0, 
    text=Size, 
    input-type=0, 
    ime-target=false
}
```

`is-selected` changes from false to true when you select the textview.

Is there a built-in way to do it in Espresso?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out, I needed a custom matcher to do so, here's the code:

```
public static Matcher<View> isTextSelected() {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if (!(view instanceof TextView)) {
                return false;
            }
            return (view).isSelected();
        }
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("is-selected=true");
        }
    };
}
```

Then call the matcher on a view: `onView(withText("XYZ")).check(matches(isTextSelected()));`

Comment: As an improvement: Instead of returning an TypeSafeMatcher, you can return new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class) {...}.The advantage is, that matchesSafely now has a TextView parameter instead of View and type checking is handled by BoundedMatcher itself.